# Повторный вывод значения формы в таблицу

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

По заданию нужно создать форму и все ее значения вывести в таблицу ниже. Вроде кое-что уже сделал, но выводятся только первые значения, а нужно чтобы при повторном вводе добавлялась строка в таблицу.

Вот [ссылка на Codepen](https://codepen.io/SlavaSvS/pen/LXPmVZ?editors=0110).

```
    function FirstName(props) {
  return (
    <label>
      First Name 
      <input type="text"
        name={props.name}
        value={props.value} 
        onChange={props.onChange}/>
    </label>
  )
}


function LastName(props) {
  return (
    <label>
      Last Name 
      <input type="text" 
        name={props.name}
        value={props.value} 
        onChange={props.onChange}/>
    </label>
  )
}


function SelectActivity(props) {
  const activityArray = ["Cooking", "Science Lab", "Painting","Swimming"];
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Select Activity</p>
    <select name={props.name}
      onChange={props.onChange}>
      {activityArray.map( (item, index) => {
        return <option key={index}> {item} </option>
    })}
    </select>  
    </div>
  )
}


function CheckApply(props) {
  return(
    <div>
      <p>Check all that apply:</p>
      {props.checkArray.map( (item, index) => {
        return (
          <label key={index}>
             <input type="checkbox"
                  name={item.id}
                  onChange={props.onChange}/>
                  {item.description}
             </label>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  )
}


function ButtonSubmit(props) {
  return (
   <button onClick={props.onClick}> Submit </button>
  )
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function TableHead() {
  const tableHeadings = ["Remove", "First Name", "Last Name", "Activity", "Restrictions"];
  return(
    <tr>
      {tableHeadings.map( (item, index) => {
        return <th>{item}</th>
      })}
    </tr>
  )
}

function TableButton(props) {
  return <td> <button> X </button> </td>
}

function TableFirstName(props) {
  return <td> {props.newArray[0]} </td>
}

function TableLastName(props) {
  return <td> {props.newArray[1]} </td>
}

function TableActivity(props) {
  return <td> {props.newArray[2]} </td>
}

function TableRestrictoins(props) {
  return <td> {props.newArray[3]} </td>
}

function TableRow(props) {
  return (
    <tr>
      <TableButton />
      <TableFirstName newArray={props.newArray} />
      <TableLastName newArray={props.newArray} />
      <TableActivity newArray={props.newArray} />
      <TableRestrictoins newArray={props.newArray} />
    </tr>
  )
}

function Table(props) {
  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <TableHead />
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <TableRow newArray={props.newArray}/>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  )
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
      activity: "",
      checkItems: "",
      newArray: [],
      checkArray: [
        {
          id: "a",
          description: "a) Dietary Restrictions"
        },
        {
          id: "b",
          description: "b) Physical Disabilities"
        },
        {
          id: "c",
          description: "c) Medical Needs"
        },
      ],
    }
    this.handleChangeName = this.handleChangeName.bind(this);
    this.handleChangeLastName = this.handleChangeLastName.bind(this);
    this.handleChangeSelect = this.handleChangeSelect.bind(this);
    this.handleChangeCheck = this.handleChangeCheck.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleChangeName(event) {
    let val = event.target.value;
    this.setState({firstName: val})
  }

  handleChangeLastName(event) {
    let val = event.target.value;
    this.setState({lastName: val})
  }

  handleChangeSelect(event) {
    let val = event.target.value;
    this.setState({activity: val})
  }

  handleChangeCheck(event) {
    this.setState({checkItems: (this.state.checkItems + event.target.name)})
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  handleClick() {
    let tempArray = [];
    tempArray.push(this.state.firstName);
    tempArray.push(this.state.lastName);
    tempArray.push(this.state.activity);
    tempArray.push(this.state.checkItems);
    this.setState({
      newArray: this.state.newArray.concat(tempArray)
    })

    this.setState({
      checkItems: "",

    })
  }


  render() {
    return(
        <React.Fragment>
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <FirstName
            name="firstName"
            onChange={this.handleChangeName}  
             />
          <LastName 
            name="lastName"
            onChange={this.handleChangeLastName}  
             />
          <SelectActivity 
            name="activity" 
            onChange={this.handleChangeSelect} />
          <CheckApply 
            checkArray = {this.state.checkArray}
            onChange={this.handleChangeCheck} />
          <ButtonSubmit onClick={this.handleClick}/>
        </form>
        <Table
         newArray = {this.state.newArray} />
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
handleClick() { 
//лучше создавать буферный объект а не массив     
let tempObject ={
  'firstName':this.state.firstName,
  'lastName':this.state.lastName,
  'activity':this.state.activity,
  'checkItems':this.state.checkItems
};

this.setState({
  newArray: this.state.newArray.concat(tempObject)
})
this.setState({
  checkItems: "",
})
}

//в props передается массив объектов 
function Table(props) {
return (
<table>
  <thead>
    <TableHead />
  </thead>
  <tbody>       
    //перебираем массив и каждый элемент(объект) передаем функции TableRow как  props 
    {props.newArray.map( (item, index) => {
      console.log(item);
    return <TableRow key = {index} newArray={item}/>
  })}
  </tbody>
</table>
)}
//получаем в props объект и выводим его свойства в каждой ячейке
function TableRow(props) {
return (
<tr>
  <TableButton />
  <td> {props.newArray.firstName} </td>
  <td> {props.newArray.lastName} </td>
  <td> {props.newArray.activity} </td>
  <td> {props.newArray.checkItems} </td>
</tr>
)}
```

лишние функции можно удалить, если помог то прими как правильный ответ.